# How can I make android transition animation between two apps?

Tags: android, android-transitions

I have two apps:

1. App1: App1_Activity01, App1_Activity02
2. App2: App2_Activity01

I created one custom transition(transition_01) and configured transition_01 as reenter transition on App1_Activity01. I have two test cases:

1. Go to App1_Activity01, open App1_Activity02, press goback button. 
   transition_01 worked fine.
2. Go to App1_Activity01, open App2_Activity01, press goback button. 
   transition_01 didn't work. it seemed transition_01 never be triggered.

Could somebody help me out for this issue? does android transition only support activities within one app?

Thanks in advance

```xml
<style name="AppTheme.Home" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementsUseOverlay">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowReenterTransition">@transition/main_reenter</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible, you need access to the Android launcher which acts as a window manager

Comment: However! the closest thing you can do is to split the transition effect between `app1` losing focus and `app2` gaining focus when moving from the former to the latter

Comment: I think I can add code to do the animation in App1_Activity02 onresume() method.